# Where do I go to ask about AR and 3D modelling?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to post a question about creating augmented reality from 3D work made in Blender, but I don't know where to go to post it? I wanted to go to [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com) but not sure if I could get an answer for the AR part, since that's what's more important. Is there a site for something like this? Do I go to Stack Overflow? That seems to be for professional developers only.

The question I wanted to post:

> I'm trying to find a way to export from Blender to an augmented reality app in order to view from the camera of a mobile device. I don't know what format to export as, and if there's any AR app that I can use on the mobile device to import the 3D work made in Blender (so that I wouldn't have to learn how to make an AR app myself). I'm just trying to get some advice from people who are more familiar with both Blender and AR. Thanks

Comment: No matter where you ask your question on the Stack Exchange network, chit chat like thanks should not be included - see [help/behavior].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that your root question is "which AR app is capable of showing models I have in Blender". That's a [software recommendation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) question. Please read their [question guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/23377) before asking - the community there gets lots of poor-quality questions and following those guidelines greatly increases your chances of getting a satisfactory answer.

Alternatively, since Blender Stack Exchange has an [[export] tag](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tags/export), you can browse that and search for "AR" or "augmented" and see what apps other users use.